# Limiting float to two decimals places

Tags: c++

This is what I have for an assignment currently and I'm wondering how to limit the outcomes to only show two decimal places.

```
const float minWage = 7.50;
const float numTax = .15;
float numHours = 0.0;
float grossPay = 0.0;
float withHoldTax = 0.0;
float netPay = 0.0;

cout << "Enter the total hours worked" << endl;
cin >> numHours;

grossPay = numHours * minWage;
withHoldTax = numTax * grossPay;
netPay = grossPay - withHoldTax;

cout << "You worked " << numHours << "hours." << endl;
cout << " " << endl;
cout << "Gross Pay is $" << grossPay << endl;
cout << "Tax collected is $" << withHoldTax << endl;
cout << "Net pay is $" << netPay << endl;




return 0;
}
```

Comment: This site is not intended to solve your homework problems ... Besides, this is very very basic. Try Google with something like "C++ string formatting". You'd be surprised what you might find.

Comment: This isn't the solution, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `fixed << setprecision(2) <<`